# How to get permissions information from an app in playstore?

Tags: python, permissions, web-crawler

I'm developing a python crawler to retrieve some information from apps in Play Store. My crawler retrieves the app rating, developer and so on, but not the permissions. That's because Google uses a fake-link and there is no html to catch. Does anyone know how to get this information? Any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to get the permissions details by scrapping the play store page.

You must use an inspection tool (I use mozilla). As you mention above, if you try to inspect the button element you will see the fake link class="content id-view-permissions-details fake-link". But if you press on "**View Details**" link, and inspect the pop-up that appears, you will find this element:
**class="permissions-container bucket-style"**
If you select right click and "Edit as HTML" you will see all the info you need:

```
     <div tabindex="0" jstcache="71" class="permissions-container bucket-style"> <div jstcache="72" class="permissions-heading" style="display:none"> This app has access to: </div> <div jstcache="73" class="permissions-heading"> Version <jsl jstcache="74">1.50.2</jsl> can access: </div> <div jstcache="75" jsinstance="0" class="permission-bucket"> <div jstcache="87" class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <jsl jstcache="110"><jsl jstcache="111"> <span class="icon billing"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> In-app purchases </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="112" style="display:none"> <span class="icon history"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device &amp; app history </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="113" style="display:none"> <span class="icon cellular-data"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Cellular data settings </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="114" style="display:none"> <span class="icon identity"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Identity </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="115" style="display:none"> <span class="icon calendar"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Calendar </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="116" style="display:none"> <span class="icon contacts"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Contacts </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="117" style="display:none"> <span class="icon location"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Location </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="118" style="display:none"> <span class="icon sms"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> SMS </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="119" style="display:none"> <span class="icon phone"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Phone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="120" style="display:none"> <span class="icon files"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Photos/Media/Files </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="121" style="display:none"> <span class="icon storage"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Storage </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="122" style="display:none"> <span class="icon camera"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Camera </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="123" style="display:none"> <span class="icon mic"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Microphone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="124" style="display:none"> <span class="icon device-id-call"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device ID &amp; call information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="125" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wifi-state"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Wi-Fi connection information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="126" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wearable"></span> <span jstcache="127" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Wearable sensors/Activity data </span> <span jstcache="128" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Body sensors </span> </jsl></jsl> </div> <div jstcache="88" style="display:none"></div> <ul jstcache="89" class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="90" style="display:none"></li> </ul> </div><div jstcache="75" jsinstance="1" class="permission-bucket"> <div jstcache="87" class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <jsl jstcache="110"><jsl jstcache="111" style="display:none"> <span class="icon billing"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> In-app purchases </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="112"> <span class="icon history"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device &amp; app history </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="113" style="display:none"> <span class="icon cellular-data"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Cellular data settings </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="114" style="display:none"> <span class="icon identity"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Identity </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="115" style="display:none"> <span class="icon calendar"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Calendar </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="116" style="display:none"> <span class="icon contacts"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Contacts </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="117" style="display:none"> <span class="icon location"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Location </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="118" style="display:none"> <span class="icon sms"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> SMS </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="119" style="display:none"> <span class="icon phone"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Phone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="120" style="display:none"> <span class="icon files"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Photos/Media/Files </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="121" style="display:none"> <span class="icon storage"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Storage </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="122" style="display:none"> <span class="icon camera"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Camera </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="123" style="display:none"> <span class="icon mic"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Microphone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="124" style="display:none"> <span class="icon device-id-call"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device ID &amp; call information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="125" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wifi-state"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Wi-Fi connection information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="126" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wearable"></span> <span jstcache="127" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Wearable sensors/Activity data </span> <span jstcache="128" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Body sensors </span> </jsl></jsl> </div> <div jstcache="88" style="display:none"></div> <ul jstcache="89" class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="90" jsinstance="*0">retrieve running apps</li> </ul> </div><div jstcache="75" jsinstance="2" class="permission-bucket"> <div jstcache="87" class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <jsl jstcache="110"><jsl jstcache="111" style="display:none"> <span class="icon billing"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> In-app purchases </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="112" style="display:none"> <span class="icon history"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device &amp; app history </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="113" style="display:none"> <span class="icon cellular-data"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Cellular data settings </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="114"> <span class="icon identity"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Identity </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="115" style="display:none"> <span class="icon calendar"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Calendar </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="116" style="display:none"> <span class="icon contacts"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Contacts </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="117" style="display:none"> <span class="icon location"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Location </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="118" style="display:none"> <span class="icon sms"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> SMS </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="119" style="display:none"> <span class="icon phone"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Phone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="120" style="display:none"> <span class="icon files"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Photos/Media/Files </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="121" style="display:none"> <span class="icon storage"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Storage </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="122" style="display:none"> <span class="icon camera"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Camera </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="123" style="display:none"> <span class="icon mic"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Microphone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="124" style="display:none"> <span class="icon device-id-call"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device ID &amp; call information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="125" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wifi-state"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Wi-Fi connection information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="126" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wearable"></span> <span jstcache="127" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Wearable sensors/Activity data </span> <span jstcache="128" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Body sensors </span> </jsl></jsl> </div> <div jstcache="88" style="display:none"></div> <ul jstcache="89" class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="90" jsinstance="*0">find accounts on the device</li> </ul> </div><div jstcache="75" jsinstance="3" class="permission-bucket"> <div jstcache="87" class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <jsl jstcache="110"><jsl jstcache="111" style="display:none"> <span class="icon billing"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> In-app purchases </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="112" style="display:none"> <span class="icon history"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device &amp; app history </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="113" style="display:none"> <span class="icon cellular-data"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Cellular data settings </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="114" style="display:none"> <span class="icon identity"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Identity </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="115" style="display:none"> <span class="icon calendar"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Calendar </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="116"> <span class="icon contacts"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Contacts </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="117" style="display:none"> <span class="icon location"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Location </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="118" style="display:none"> <span class="icon sms"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> SMS </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="119" style="display:none"> <span class="icon phone"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Phone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="120" style="display:none"> <span class="icon files"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Photos/Media/Files </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="121" style="display:none"> <span class="icon storage"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Storage </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="122" style="display:none"> <span class="icon camera"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Camera </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="123" style="display:none"> <span class="icon mic"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Microphone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="124" style="display:none"> <span class="icon device-id-call"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device ID &amp; call information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="125" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wifi-state"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Wi-Fi connection information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="126" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wearable"></span> <span jstcache="127" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Wearable sensors/Activity data </span> <span jstcache="128" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Body sensors </span> </jsl></jsl> </div> <div jstcache="88" style="display:none"></div> <ul jstcache="89" class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="90" jsinstance="*0">find accounts on the device</li> </ul> </div><div jstcache="75" jsinstance="4" class="permission-bucket"> <div jstcache="87" class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <jsl jstcache="110"><jsl jstcache="111" style="display:none"> <span class="icon billing"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> In-app purchases </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="112" style="display:none"> <span class="icon history"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device &amp; app history </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="113" style="display:none"> <span class="icon cellular-data"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Cellular data settings </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="114" style="display:none"> <span class="icon identity"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Identity </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="115" style="display:none"> <span class="icon calendar"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Calendar </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="116" style="display:none"> <span class="icon contacts"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Contacts </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="117" style="display:none"> <span class="icon location"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Location </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="118" style="display:none"> <span class="icon sms"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> SMS </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="119"> <span class="icon phone"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Phone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="120" style="display:none"> <span class="icon files"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Photos/Media/Files </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="121" style="display:none"> <span class="icon storage"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Storage </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="122" style="display:none"> <span class="icon camera"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Camera </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="123" style="display:none"> <span class="icon mic"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Microphone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="124" style="display:none"> <span class="icon device-id-call"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device ID &amp; call information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="125" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wifi-state"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Wi-Fi connection information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="126" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wearable"></span> <span jstcache="127" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Wearable sensors/Activity data </span> <span jstcache="128" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Body sensors </span> </jsl></jsl> </div> <div jstcache="88" style="display:none"></div> <ul jstcache="89" class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="90" jsinstance="*0">read phone status and identity</li> </ul> </div><div jstcache="75" jsinstance="5" class="permission-bucket"> <div jstcache="87" class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <jsl jstcache="110"><jsl jstcache="111" style="display:none"> <span class="icon billing"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> In-app purchases </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="112" style="display:none"> <span class="icon history"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device &amp; app history </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="113" style="display:none"> <span class="icon cellular-data"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Cellular data settings </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="114" style="display:none"> <span class="icon identity"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Identity </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="115" style="display:none"> <span class="icon calendar"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Calendar </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="116" style="display:none"> <span class="icon contacts"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Contacts </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="117" style="display:none"> <span class="icon location"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Location </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="118" style="display:none"> <span class="icon sms"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> SMS </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="119" style="display:none"> <span class="icon phone"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Phone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="120"> <span class="icon files"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Photos/Media/Files </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="121" style="display:none"> <span class="icon storage"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Storage </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="122" style="display:none"> <span class="icon camera"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Camera </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="123" style="display:none"> <span class="icon mic"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Microphone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="124" style="display:none"> <span class="icon device-id-call"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device ID &amp; call information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="125" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wifi-state"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Wi-Fi connection information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="126" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wearable"></span> <span jstcache="127" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Wearable sensors/Activity data </span> <span jstcache="128" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Body sensors </span> </jsl></jsl> </div> <div jstcache="88" style="display:none"></div> <ul jstcache="89" class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="90" jsinstance="0">modify or delete the contents of your USB storage</li><li jstcache="90" jsinstance="*1">read the contents of your USB storage</li> </ul> </div><div jstcache="75" jsinstance="6" class="permission-bucket"> <div jstcache="87" class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <jsl jstcache="110"><jsl jstcache="111" style="display:none"> <span class="icon billing"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> In-app purchases </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="112" style="display:none"> <span class="icon history"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device &amp; app history </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="113" style="display:none"> <span class="icon cellular-data"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Cellular data settings </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="114" style="display:none"> <span class="icon identity"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Identity </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="115" style="display:none"> <span class="icon calendar"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Calendar </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="116" style="display:none"> <span class="icon contacts"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Contacts </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="117" style="display:none"> <span class="icon location"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Location </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="118" style="display:none"> <span class="icon sms"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> SMS </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="119" style="display:none"> <span class="icon phone"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Phone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="120" style="display:none"> <span class="icon files"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Photos/Media/Files </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="121"> <span class="icon storage"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Storage </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="122" style="display:none"> <span class="icon camera"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Camera </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="123" style="display:none"> <span class="icon mic"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Microphone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="124" style="display:none"> <span class="icon device-id-call"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device ID &amp; call information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="125" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wifi-state"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Wi-Fi connection information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="126" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wearable"></span> <span jstcache="127" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Wearable sensors/Activity data </span> <span jstcache="128" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Body sensors </span> </jsl></jsl> </div> <div jstcache="88" style="display:none"></div> <ul jstcache="89" class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="90" jsinstance="0">modify or delete the contents of your USB storage</li><li jstcache="90" jsinstance="*1">read the contents of your USB storage</li> </ul> </div><div jstcache="75" jsinstance="7" class="permission-bucket"> <div jstcache="87" class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <jsl jstcache="110"><jsl jstcache="111" style="display:none"> <span class="icon billing"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> In-app purchases </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="112" style="display:none"> <span class="icon history"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device &amp; app history </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="113" style="display:none"> <span class="icon cellular-data"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Cellular data settings </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="114" style="display:none"> <span class="icon identity"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Identity </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="115" style="display:none"> <span class="icon calendar"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Calendar </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="116" style="display:none"> <span class="icon contacts"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Contacts </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="117" style="display:none"> <span class="icon location"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Location </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="118" style="display:none"> <span class="icon sms"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> SMS </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="119" style="display:none"> <span class="icon phone"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Phone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="120" style="display:none"> <span class="icon files"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Photos/Media/Files </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="121" style="display:none"> <span class="icon storage"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Storage </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="122" style="display:none"> <span class="icon camera"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Camera </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="123" style="display:none"> <span class="icon mic"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Microphone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="124" style="display:none"> <span class="icon device-id-call"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device ID &amp; call information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="125"> <span class="icon wifi-state"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Wi-Fi connection information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="126" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wearable"></span> <span jstcache="127" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Wearable sensors/Activity data </span> <span jstcache="128" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Body sensors </span> </jsl></jsl> </div> <div jstcache="88" style="display:none"></div> <ul jstcache="89" class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="90" jsinstance="*0">view Wi-Fi connections</li> </ul> </div><div jstcache="75" jsinstance="*8" class="permission-bucket"> <div jstcache="87" class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <jsl jstcache="110"><jsl jstcache="111" style="display:none"> <span class="icon billing"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> In-app purchases </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="112" style="display:none"> <span class="icon history"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device &amp; app history </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="113" style="display:none"> <span class="icon cellular-data"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Cellular data settings </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="114" style="display:none"> <span class="icon identity"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Identity </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="115" style="display:none"> <span class="icon calendar"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Calendar </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="116" style="display:none"> <span class="icon contacts"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Contacts </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="117" style="display:none"> <span class="icon location"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Location </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="118" style="display:none"> <span class="icon sms"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> SMS </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="119" style="display:none"> <span class="icon phone"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Phone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="120" style="display:none"> <span class="icon files"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Photos/Media/Files </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="121" style="display:none"> <span class="icon storage"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Storage </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="122" style="display:none"> <span class="icon camera"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Camera </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="123" style="display:none"> <span class="icon mic"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Microphone </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="124"> <span class="icon device-id-call"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Device ID &amp; call information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="125" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wifi-state"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Wi-Fi connection information </span> </jsl><jsl jstcache="126" style="display:none"> <span class="icon wearable"></span> <span jstcache="127" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Wearable sensors/Activity data </span> <span jstcache="128" class="bucket-title" style="display:none"> Body sensors </span> </jsl></jsl> </div> <div jstcache="88" style="display:none"></div> <ul jstcache="89" class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="90" jsinstance="*0">read phone status and identity</li> </ul> </div> <jsl jstcache="76"> <div class="permission-bucket"> <div class="bucket-icon-and-title"> <span class="icon other"></span> <span class="bucket-title"> Other </span> </div> <ul class="bucket-description"> <li jstcache="78" jsinstance="0">download files without notification</li><li jstcache="78" jsinstance="*1">receive data from Internet</li> <jsl jstcache="79" jsinstance="*0"> <li jstcache="80" jsinstance="0">full network access</li><li jstcache="80" jsinstance="1">Google Play license check</li><li jstcache="80" jsinstance="2">view network connections</li><li jstcache="80" jsinstance="3">connect and disconnect from Wi-Fi</li><li jstcache="80" jsinstance="4">prevent device from sleeping</li><li jstcache="80" jsinstance="*5">control vibration</li> </jsl> </ul> </div> </jsl> </div>
```

The best way to retrieve the information you want is to do an HTTP POST request to the url: https://play.google.com/store/xhr/ructx?authuser=0 with parameters:

id   "id=com.kiloo.subwaysurf"

xhr "1"

hl  "en"   //for English

You can find all the headers from the inspection tool:

HOST    "play.google.com"

ACCEPT        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"

CONTENT-TYPE     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"

REFERER       "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiloo.subwaysurf&hl=en"

Then you can use any API you want to send the POST request. For ease, I used curl:

```
    curl --data "ids=com.kiloo.subwaysurf&xhr=1&hl=en" https://play.google.com/store/xhr/getdoc?authuser=0 --silent
```

But python has a great API for HTTP requests.
The difficult part will be to parse the response in a automated way.
The result is JSON and I don't know how google parses it to human readable information.

You may also find information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087971/how-to-parse-the-json-data-in-the-web-page-of-google-play).